# Minimal MinGW-w64 without additional libraries

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

[Prebuild](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.2.0/threads-posix/seh/) `MinGW-w64` comes with lots of handy built-in packages such as `openssl`, `sqlite`, `python`, `d3d` and others.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get or build from sources a minimal `MinGW-w64` toolchain without the extra libs
that it comes with.

What I think it should include is:

- binutils
- clib
- gcc/g++
- posix thread

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Try http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

Comment: @NeilButterworth I came across TDM as well, but it seems like it is a dead project. No gcc 7 for instance. I'll give it a try anyways.

Comment: If you are complaining about stuff like having `python.exe` in `mingw64/opt/bin`, you could just delete the `opt` directory

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on it I think that [WinBuilds](http://win-builds.org) is the best solution so far: it provides a GUI which allows to cherry pick the components you need to install in your toolchain.

I'm walking away from *building from source* because tedious and poorly documented.

*TDM* works fine with shipped gcc/g++ but since there is some [hacking](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/quirks) going on regarding threading, using other compilers like clang or an up-to-date gcc version is off the table.